# 17.04 Printer Drivers?

Tags: 17.04

How does the new printer driver system work in 17.04? I heard that printer drivers were going to be added to the tree similar to other drivers, but my `Brother MFC-J410W` doesn't seem to have a default driver installed right off the bat. Will printer drivers be added gradually as time goes on, or am I just not configuring the printer properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many printers will load by default, particularly HP.

Brother, however, does provide specific drivers for Linux, packaged in the .deb format for Ubuntu.  You can find the drivers for your printer [here](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=mfcj410w_us&os=128)

Comment: I have the driver installed :D. I was just wondering if there were any plans to have Brother printers have similar functionality.